# How can I add dynamic tool tip to a column in kendo mvc grid

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

.HtmlAttributes(new { title = "#= UserApprovalRemark #" })

It doesn't works for adding a dynamic tool tip for kendo mvc grid.
[this gives the model name itself as output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KGaRh.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have mixed that with the jQuery version of kendo.

For asp.net-mvc this may work for you:

```
.HtmlAttributes(new { @title = "UserApprovalRemark" })
```